# Объединить строки в pandas

Tags: python, pandas, таблицы

Не хватает пока знаний в pandas разобраться самому. Нужно сгруппировать данные по дням так, чтобы из таблицы типа:

```
    Day         A  B  C 
1   2019-12-10  5  4  1  

2   2019-12-10  3  1  6

3   2019-12-11  1  5  2

4   2019-12-11  3  3  6
```

получилось так:

```
    Day         A  B  C  A1  B1  C1
1   2019-12-10  5  4  1  3   1   6 

2   2019-12-11  1  5  2  3   3   6
```

Значения разнятся в зависимости от времени получения в течении одного дня.

Реальные данные:

```
        Time    Open    High    Low     Close   Volume
0   2019-12-30  1.12026 1.12051 1.12026 1.12036 189
1   2019-12-30  1.12036 1.12037 1.12014 1.12027 193
2   2019-12-30  1.12027 1.12029 1.12023 1.12029 113
3   2019-12-31  1.12027 1.12028 1.12003 1.12006 217
4   2019-12-31  1.12006 1.12021 1.12005 1.12019 143
```

Comment: Почему у вас за один день разные значения цен открытия/закрытия и т.д., вероятно, это по разным бумагам? Ну тогда у вас не хватает колонки с названием бумаги. Что вы в итоге то хотите получить и зачем?

Comment: получены в разное время, данные о времени я уже удалил за ненадобностью

Comment: Хочу дополнить таблицу присоединенными строками за один день

Comment: Но **ЗАЧЕМ**?! Если вы хотите посчитать какую-то статистику - так считайте её сразу при группировке и добавляйте в таблицу именно статистику - среднее, стандартное отклонение и т.д. А если вам важно как ситуация развивалась в течении дня, то я не понимаю, зачем вы удалили время. В общем, непонятна цель, без понимания цели нет смысла что-то делать. Мне кажется вы делаете лишнюю, ненужную работу.

Comment: Разве что вы оставили данные за некоторые фиксированные моменты по каждому дню, тогда ещё как-то могу понять, но опять же надо было тогда оставить колонку где время и прибавлять это время к названию добавляемых столбцов. Не могу понять, в чём смысл терять информацию, которую можно было хоть как-то использовать.

Comment: Для решения моей задачи нужно, чтобы все строки, по ключу - уникальный день, были в одной строке. При этом каждое значение должно быть в уникальном столбце. Вы примерно правильно поняли логику. Но в вашем коде не сохранен порядок следования вновь созданных столбцов (это важно). Я так понимаю, что c pandas можно решить эту проблему?

Comment: Значения времени можно вернуть, если для решения задачи они будут нужны

Answer (score 0):

Предположим, есть датафрейм:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({"Day":["2019-12-10", "2019-12-10", "2019-12-11", "2019-12-11"],
                   "A":[5,3,1,3],
                   "B":[4, 1, 5, 3],
                   "C":[1,6,2,6]})
```

```
         Day  A  B  C
0  2019-12-10  5  4  1
1  2019-12-10  3  1  6
2  2019-12-11  1  5  2
3  2019-12-11  3  3  6
```

Тогда:

```
df1 = df.groupby('Day').aggregate(lambda x: list(x)).reset_index()
res = df1.iloc[:,:1]
for col in df1.columns[1:]:
    res = res.join(pd.DataFrame(df1[col].to_list(),
                                columns=[col+str(x) for x in range(1, len(df1.columns)-1)]))
```

получаем res:

```
          Day  A1  A2  B1  B2  C1  C2
0  2019-12-10   5   3   4   1   1   6
1  2019-12-11   1   3   5   3   2   6
```

Мне кажется, что это немного неуклюжее решение, но ничего более оптимального пока в голову не приходит.

Comment: К сожалению такой способ мне не подойдет. Нужно чтобы порядок колонок А В С сохранялся: А1 В1 С1 А2 В2 С2 и т.д.

Comment: К тому же на моём df такой код выдает ошибку: AssertionError: 4 columns passed, passed data had 288 columns

Comment: а вы приведите кусок реального примера данных.

Comment: Выше привел реальную таблицу